# Folktale: combine Result and Task (or just promise)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, folktale

It's a bite of broken code:

```
async function foo() {
  return maybeMonad
    .map((resultMonad) => resultMonad
      .matchWith({
        Error: (errorMonad) => errorMonad,
        Ok: (okMonad) => okMonad
          .map(async (context) => {
            let res = await apiRequest(context.token);
            context.data = res.data;
  
            return context;
          }),
      }));
}


await foo() // => Maybe(Promise)
```

The idea is to get some value from context, make a request and return context with supplemented data. But it returns a Promise in pending status. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Promises are in pending status until they resolve, so what's your problem? Also how are you getting Maybe(Promise) out of an async function? They implicitly wrap their return value in a Promise.

Comment: apiRequest resolves OK, but foo returns maybe with unresolved promise instead maybe with result

Comment: I think we're going to need a little more info about what you're actually trying to accomplish here...I'm not an *expert* in folktale/fantasyland but unless I'm completely mistaken your usage looks off. You have a lot of closure variables here that don't square with FP in general and in your specific question we probably need to see in order to help.

Comment: I don't think you should (can) use `async` functions to combine tasks.

Comment: Please be more specific what the code is supposed to do here. All those variable names ending in `monad` are quite meaningless - and probably wrong: types are monads, values are not.

Comment: As I have already said I need make an async api request with value from `context.token` and modify context with data getted from this request. I don't think I be able more specific.

`resultMonad` and `okMonad` both are monads (Result and Result.Ok). Only `context` is plain object.

Comment: `Also how are you getting Maybe(Promise) out of an async function?`
I don't think that I understood the question.

Comment: So =) let's try again?